# SVG filter inheritance

Tags: browser, svg, svg-filters

According to these sources:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href (~75% down)

the SVG `filter` element can inherit from another filter via the `xlink:href` attribute. Problem is I can't get my code running in neither Chrome 19 nor FF 10. My test code can be found in the fiddle below. I've tried both with and without enclosing the IRI reference with `url(...)`. Am I doing something wrong or is the feature simply not implemented yet?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WJafz/ (another red blob is supposed to appear in lower right corner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was implemented in Firefox 14 via https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739591